# PowerShell: Replacing with a variable that has backslashes

Tags: powershell

I am starting in the path:

`D:\starting\path`

This path has subfolders:

`D:\starting\path\sub\01`

`D:\starting\path\sub\02`

and files:

`D:\starting\path\sub\01\fileA.txt`

`D:\starting\path\sub\01\fileB.txt`

Ultimately, I want the files to incorporate the folders under the starting folder in the their file anmes. Namely:

`D:\starting\path\sub\01\fileA (sub-01).txt`

`D:\starting\path\sub\02\fileB (sub-02).txt`

I have tried the following one-line script with no success.

```
D:\starting\path> $startPath=(Get-Location); $startPath=($startPath -replace "\\","\\"); $startPath=($startPath+"\\"); Get-ChildItem -file -recurse | foreach-object {$currentPath=($_.Directory.ToString() -replace "\\","\\"); $append=((($currentPath -replace "${startPath}","") -replace "\\\\","-")); $append=(" ("+$append+")"); $new=($_.directory.ToString()+"\"+$_.BaseName+$append+$_.extension); echo $_.fullname $new}
```

Note: The one-liner above has been updated from original to replace `$append=((($_.directory -replace "${startPath}","") -replace "\\","-"));` with `$currentPath=($_.Directory.ToString() -replace "\\","\\"); $append=((($currentPath -replace "${startPath}","") -replace "\\\\","-"));`. The `$_.directory -replace ...` in the original failed to convert it to a string and then change single backslashes to double backslashes. This would have created problems in and of itself but did not solve the original problem.

The script returns the following output:

`D:\starting\path\sub\01\fileA (D:-starting-path-sub-01).txt`

`D:\starting\path\sub\02\fileB (D:-starting-path-sub-02).txt`

The problem clearly lies somewhere in the first `-replace` but I do not know why. It clearly has to do something with the path `D:\starting\path` being inside a variable rather than being manually entered as a string. What is special about the path being stored in a string to cause this? I have also tried the same script except I removed `$startPath=($startPath -replace "\\","\\");`

Your guidance is appreciated.

note: The `echo $_.fullname $new` will ultimately be `mv $_ $new` but I use echo during testing.

---

### UPDATE

Script in block form (minor update and one fix made ... but doesn't solve original problem)

```
# Assume
# D:\start\path
$startPath=(Get-Location) # D:\start\path
$startPath=($startPath -replace "\\","\\") # D:\\start\\path
$startPath=($startPath+"\\") # D:\\start\\path\\
Get-ChildItem -recurse | foreach-object {
    $currentPath=(($_.directory.ToString()) -replace "\\","\\")
    $append=((($currentPath -replace "${startPath}","") -replace "\\\\","-")) 
    # first replace D:\\start\\path\\sub\\01 --> sub\\01 (THIS ISN'T HAPPENING)
    # second replace sub\\01 --> sub-01
    $append=(" ("+$append+")")
    $new=($_.directory.ToString()+"\"+$_.BaseName+$append+$_.extension)
    echo $_.fullname $new
}
```

The `$currentPath` and `$startPath` variables in `$append=((($currentPath -replace "${startPath}","") -replace "\\\\","-"))` are returning the expected strings. That is, `$currentPath: D:\\start\\path\\sub\\01` and `$startPath: D:\\start\\path\\`. Why the `$startPath` isn't being replace with `""` in `$currentPath` is unclear.

Comment: Try doing this as not-a-one-liner and insert some `Write-Host` cmdlets at various stages to see what the intermediate results are. Then, edit your question to include what you **want** to happen, *and* what actually **does** happen.

Comment: In the original post, what I wanted output was already detailed. I do not want to write it as anything but a one-liner script. I need to understand why this is happening as a one-liner as I intend to use similar one-liners in the future. I have updated the post to provide an example of what output is being produced.

Comment: But that is not a one-Liner at all. It's a full script using semi-colons to allow code all on one line. That being said, in your troubleshooting effort, doing this in real PS Editor ISE/VSCode, using breakpoints to stop at given points and then inspecting, is what I believe Jeff Zeitlin is suggesting. He is not just randomly suggesting that you not put this all on one line. If you are doing this at the interactive consolehost session, then that makes sense, but doing this in a true saved/production script is just industry bad practice. Yet, we all make a choice & this has to be split to check

Comment: Split, meaning anyone trying to help you, has to break this long string into a real script to troubleshoot. To truly see what is actually going on.  Just my quick look at this, after doing the aforementioned, points to several things, I'd call into question. Yet, again, if you again, break into a troubleshooting format, you could see what I am driving at. Now, once all the troubleshooting is done, you can concatenate back all code on one line.

Comment: Agreed. Based on what the OP says they are after, the first 3 lines are not warranted at all. A simple Read-Host to a variable and paring that in a loop would be more prudent.

Comment: Pro tip: $startPath=($startPath -replace "\\","\\") does nothing. And $startPath=($startPath+"\\") adds double backslashes to the string, i.e. $startpath=C:\Windows\System32, after your two steps it becomes C:\Windows\System32\\

Comment: @ Xeнεi Ξэnвϵς, since `-replace` treats the first group as regex, `\\` is needed to represent a single `\` and the second group of `replace` treats `\\` as a literal (i.e. two backslashes). So, `$startPath -replace "\\","\\"` converts a string from single to double backslashes. I did this since the `$startPath` variable is used later in `... -replace "$startPath",""`. With it, errors are thrown if there are only single backslashes. As for adding the double backslash, that was intentional for the same reason I just cited. Try the script I wrote in PS but without those to see the errors thrown.

Comment: @postanote. I appreciate where you are coming from and can change it. The problem that sometimes occurs (due to nuisances I do not understand) is that when a script is written as a multiline script and executed as a .ps1 script, it may run without problems. But, as soon as it is concatenated it will still have problems. That's why I presented it as a  one-liner. I want the one-liner to work. This being said, I am changing it now.

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς I strongly suspect this is the issue. OP - when you try to replace $startPath in $_.directory, startPath has already had a slash added to the end. I don't know what $_.directory is returning, but if it returns the path without a final slash that would explain why it's not matching. EDIT: Just saw that you're actually replacing all the slashes with double slashes. That's almost definitely the issue. What exactly is $_.directory outputting?

Comment: E.g., If you do "C:\Some\Path" -replace "C:\\Some\\Path\\" "" then it's not going to match.

Comment: Based on the OP ultimate goal, if I am making the correct assumptions; all the replacement stuff is not needed at all. Of which I tried to reflect in my answer. Yet, we all know the old adage about `'assume'`.

Comment: And @Brian... I just edited a typo in the last piece of PS code you added and fixed a `- replace` with....... `-replace`... Make sure that's not a typo in the code you are running though.

Answer (score 2):

Use [conditional](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html) logic for better control and avoid null command parameter errors. Don't use `-replace` and   just [join](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-7.1) together the last two folders with split using the index values `[-1..-2]`.

Join the two folders back together with the hyphen character `-`. Use the [subexpression operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html) to create the `$append` variable as a string and wrap it with a parenthesis.

Now concatenate that to the file name before the extension at the end of the base file name.

#### PowerShell

```
$startPath = (Get-Location);
$startPath = "$($startPath.Split("\") -join "\\")\\";
Get-ChildItem $startPath -recurse | % { Process {
    If( $_.directory ) { $currentPath = $(($_.directory.ToString()).Replace("\\","\\"))};
    $append = "($($currentPath.Split("\")[-1..-2] -join "-"))";
    $new = If( $_.directory ) { ( "$($_.directory.ToString())\$($_.BaseName)$append$($_.extension)" ) };
    echo $_.fullname $new
}};
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [If()](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html)
- [Split()](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)
- [-join](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-7.1)
- [PowerShell Operators $( ) @( ) :: &](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html)

Comment: I also threw in a couple other less variables to set too. This should get you what you see @Brian.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment.

For troubleshooting in the ISE or VSCode:

This...

```
$startPath=(Get-Location); $startPath=($startPath -replace "\\","\\"); $startPath=($startPath+"\\"); Get-ChildItem -recurse | foreach-object {$append=((($_.directory -replace "${startPath}","") -replace "\\","-")); $append=(" ("+$append+")"); $new=($_.directory.ToString()+"\"+$_.BaseName+$append+$_.extension); echo $_.fullname $new}
```

...becomes this...

```
$startPath = 'D:\Temp'
$startPath = ($startPath -replace "\\","\\")
$startPath = ($startPath+"\\")

Get-ChildItem -recurse | 
foreach-object {
$append = (
    (
        ($_.directory -replace "${startPath}","") -replace 
        "\\","-"
    )
)
    
$append = (" ("+$append+")")
$new    = ($_.directory.ToString()+"\"+$_.BaseName+$append+$_.extension)

echo $_.fullname $new}
```

... immediately all the bad stuff stands out and then after you step thru it, is this what you were after ( a true one-liner):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a starting path') -File -Recurse | 
Select-Object -First 9 | 
foreach-object {"$($PSItem.BaseName) - $($PSItem.Directory)$($PSItem.Extension)"}
# Results
<#
abc - Copy - Copy - D:\temp.bat
abc - Copy - D:\temp.bat
abc - D:\temp.bat
about_Redirection  Microsoft Docs - D:\temp.url
aes - D:\temp.key
available13.html.2019-03-26_081523 - D:\temp.bak
#>
```

***Point of note:***

Programatically speaking, special characters, spaces, in the directory, filenames, variable names, property names, et all, is a very bad idea long term.

For stuff you inherit or that is already in place, we all have to deal with that, but for stuff, you control and or can manipulate, well, you know.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally guessed what you want, and I have written a script from scratch, I haven't tested it because I can't use a computer right now, but it should do what you want:

```
$startdir=Read-Host "Please input starting path"
$files=(Get-ChildItem -Path $startdir -File -Force -Recurse).FullName
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $directories=(Split-Path -Path $file -Parent).split("\")
    $parent=$directories | Select-Object -Last 1
    $grandparent=$directories | Select-Object -Index $($directories.count - 2)
    $name=[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
    $extension=$file.split(".") | Select-Object -Last 1
    Rename-Item -Path $file -NewName $($name+" ("+$grandparent+"-"+$parent+")."+$extension)
}
```

Save as a .ps1 file, and it should give you what you want.

Comment: @DrinkSomePimpJuiceIT Nope, the -File parameter specifies the result should only list the files and not directories, the -Force parameter makes Get-ChildItem list hidden files.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a lot of working answers, but I want to join the fun :-)

```
$Path = Get-Location | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path
Get-ChildItem $Path -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $Rename = $_.Directory -replace ([regex]::Escape($Path) + "\\"),'' -replace '\\','-'
    $NewName = "{0} ({1}){2}" -f $_.BaseName, $Rename, $_.Extension
    Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName $NewName -WhatIf
}
```

`$Path` can also be a string like `$Path = "D:\start\path"`

What's good about this is that through `-replace ([regex]::Escape($Path) + "\\"),''` we basically delete the "starting path" from the string, and then we can simply replace all `\` with `'` and we're done. That's the whole magic and will work no matter how many subdirectories you have and how deep they go.

You can run this script for testing as it is and it won't rename anything because of the `-WhatIf`. It will only tell you what it does. But if you found that it does everything as it should, you can replace `-WhatIf` with `-Force`

Answer (score 0):

I can finally read OP's code, and I recognized why it isn't working.

First, the second, third and fifth lines of code are unnecessary and should be removed

Second, the -replace operator uses regex matches, so we need to use double backslashes for literal backslashes, however here we are not trying to do regex matches(there is only one possible matching value for the starting directory), so it is better to use .replace() method instead.

Third, the Get-Location cmdlet requires you to Set-Location first, better use Read-Host so you can process any location without having to change directory first.

The fixed code:

```
$startPath=Read-Host "Please input start path" # Input D:\Start\Path\
Get-ChildItem -path $startPath -file -force -recurse | foreach-object {
    $append=" ("+$_.directory.ToString().replace($startPath).replace("\","-")+")"
    $new=($_.directory.ToString()+"\"+$_.BaseName+$append+$_.extension)
    echo $_.fullname $new
}
```

Try the fixed code, I haven't tested it because I am unable to do so at the moment, so please test it and tell me the results so I can further improve it, however I think it should be working.

Save as a .ps1 file(e.g. script.ps1) and cd (or sl) to its location and use something like .\script.ps1 to invoke it.

---

Inspired by this answer https://superuser.com/a/1625400/1250181, I further improved my code:

```
$startPath=Read-Host "Please input start path" # Input D:\Start\Path\
Get-ChildItem -path $startPath -file -force -recurse | foreach-object {
    $append=" ("+$($_.directory.ToString().Split("\")[-1..-2] -join "-")+")"
    $new=($_.directory.ToString()+"\"+$_.BaseName+$append+$_.extension)
    echo $_.fullname $new
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you don't need to be using Search & replace & worrying about escaping backslashes. Here's my take on what you asked for. All the logic is easily contained within the `-NewName` ScriptBlock as the name is constructed from elements of the file's fully-qualified path.

```
(Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse) | Rename-Item -NewName {
    $Ancestors = $_.DirectoryName.Split('\')
    '{0} ({1}-{2}){3}'-f $_.BaseName, $Ancestors[-2], $Ancestors[-1], $_.Extension
}
```

[Rename-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-5.1)

[-f (Format operator)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f)

---

- **Note:** While several other answers use the `-Force` parameter with `Get-ChildItem`, I wouldn't in this case. Doing so would rename
  `desktop.ini`files, breaking things like custom folder icons.

---

Answer (score 0):

I use `-replace '\\', '/'` to achieve this goal.

```
 Liu.D.H  $CIPHEY_CORE_PYTHON=(Split-Path -Parent (Get-Command python.exe).Path)
 Liu.D.H  $CIPHEY_CORE_PYTHON=($CIPHEY_CORE_PYTHON -replace '\\', '/')
 Liu.D.H  echo $CIPHEY_CORE_PYTHON
C:/Users/Liu.D.H/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311
 Liu.D.H  echo ((Split-Path -Parent (Get-Command python.exe).Path) -replace '\\', '/')
C:/Users/Liu.D.H/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311
 Liu.D.H   ~   
```